# Difference between import and import from

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm looking through some ES6/browserify tutorials and I see something like:

```
import 'jquery';
import domready from 'domready';
```

What is the difference between import and import from?

If I use just import domready - domready fails to work.

Comment: There's not `jQuery` variable in your import statement, but there is a `domready` one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line

```
import 'jquery';
// is functionally equivalent to
require('jquery');
```

Your second line

```
import domready from 'domready';
// is technically equivalent to
var domready = require('domready');
```

So you can probably see why the second one is the only one that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at-
[mozilla reference for import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Posting as answer because I do not have enough reputation to make a comment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason jQuery still works is because of what `jquery` does. If you look at the source of the jquery library, it sets itself as `window.jQuery`. This creates the `jQuery` and `$` variables in the global scope, so you can still use the variables `jQuery` and `$`. the `domready` library does not. It returns an instance of itself, so you *have* to save that to a variable using import from.