# What is the correct way to import jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, browserify

I've asked similar questions but they are not the same as this one, I am asking again as to make the question clearer.

```
import 'jquery';
import domready from 'domready';

import Menu from './Menu';

class App {
    constructor() {
        domready(() => {
            this.init();
        });
    }

    init() {
        console.log($('.menu-btn'));
        new Menu();
    }

}

new App();

export default App;
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

When I do something like:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Jquery becomes available in my App script but not in another other scripts such as menu.

What is the correct way to import jquery for use across all scripts?

Comment: Your going to get in trouble. You're supposed to edit your original question instead of asking 3+ questions about the same thing.

Comment: This may be a dupe, but not of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107689/difference-between-import-and-import-from

Answer (score 2):

> Jquery becomes available in my App script but not in another other scripts such as menu.

Your menu script is *also* meant to import it. That way, each script declares its dependencies, which is useful for analysis, etc. They will share a common instance of jQuery.